# Sending data To external services using Record-Triggerd

Tags: visual-workflow, external-services, recordtriggeredflow

[image]

I have a Record Trigger Flow in Salesforce responsible for sending data to external services. The key requirement is for this flow to trigger only once, specifically when there's a change in the Tag field—a text field where I use the "contains" operator to detect alterations.I also used schedule path but its also not working

To enforce the trigger-only-once condition, I've come up with a strategy. I store all Tag values in another text field. Within the Flow's design, I check whether the current Tag value exists in the stored values. If it does, I skip the second assignment.

While this strategy works flawlessly in the debug logs, it's not triggering as expected when tested on the UI.

Any suggestion would be great

Thank You

Comment: Can you not use "is updated to meet conditions" in your entry criteria? It would help if you could include the full entry criteria in the question (use [edit] to add).

Comment: My entry condition are all isChanged ,i added 4 entry condition and all the fields i am using in decision

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the exact entry conditions.